# How to add a condition for the query so that it can calculate the unique months and years in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I write down the condition so that he counts the months for me from a certain client (redirect) and source (source)? I need to know how many invoices were issued, and this is counted by month, type January and February are 2 invoices, March April June 3 invoices, etc. I could write max instead of count, but this is not correct, since the client may appear in the middle of the year, for example in May, and he will have the values of the maximum month.

Here is my request:

```
select TA.redirect, 
  count(case when TA.source='zlat1' then extract(month from TA.date) else 0 end) number_of_accounts_zlat1,  
  count(case when TA.source='zlat2' then extract(month from TA.date) else 0 end) number_of_accounts_zlat2,  
  sum(TA.result_for_the_day) accrued
from total_accounts TA
group by TA.redirect
```

Here are tables and data + query and result ---->

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0bc8002e59b03afedeac8d1b8dfc98d1

Comment: It is advisable to add your desired output

Comment: the result table is the desired result @learning

Comment: will you explain how you derive the result for 'JON'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into finace_base (redirect)
select distinct Ta.redirect /*this select will display those names that are not present
                              in FB if there is other info that u must add to insert then
                              just add , next to redirect and add whatever u like*/
from total_acounts TA
left join finace_base FB on TA.redirect=FB.redirect
where FB.redirect is null;
update finace_base FB
set zlat1=TA.zlat1,
    zlat2=TA.zlat2,
    accrued=TA.accrued
    from (select TA.redirect,
                 count(*) filter ( where TA.source='zlat1' ) as zlat1,
                 count(*) filter ( where TA.source='zlat2' ) as zlat2,
                 sum(TA.accrued) as accrued
          from(
                  select sum(TA.accrued) as accrued,
                         TA.date,
                         TA.redirect,
                         TA.source
                  from (select TA.result_for_the_day as accrued,
                               to_char(TA.date, 'yyyy-mm') as date,
                               TA.redirect,
                               TA.source
                        from total_accounts TA) TA
                  group by TA.redirect, TA.date, TA.source) TA
          group by TA.redirect) TA
    where FB.redirect=TA.redirect
```

i could not add it into comments cause it was too long essentialy you first run the insert into statement and then update it will only do inserts for redirects that are not added yet

Comment: returns an error, the "id" column is of type integer, but the expression is of type text

Comment: i think the database requires u to have an id for finace_base which u are not providing, it should assing ids automaticaly if u have sequence added to it which u should do and make sure to increase its value to something high

Comment: it whould help if you told me what other columns are in finace_base

Comment: create table finace_base (
id serial primary key,
redirect text,
number_of_accounts_zlat1 int,
number_of_accounts_zlat2 int,
accrued numeric
)

but in the future I wanted to add a couple more columns, if possible

Comment: it turns out that you need to make the id generate itself, is it necessary in the condition, or should the column itself be made like this?

Answer (score 0):

```
select TA.redirect,
   count(*) filter ( where TA.source='zlat1' ) as zlat1,
   count(*) filter ( where TA.source='zlat2' ) as zlat2,
   sum(TA.accrued)    
from(
select sum(TA.accrued) as accrued,
   TA.date,
   TA.redirect,
   TA.source
from (select TA.result_for_the_day as accrued,
         to_char(TA.date, 'yyyy-mm') as date,
         TA.redirect,
         TA.source
  from total_accounts TA) TA
group by TA.redirect, TA.date, TA.source) TA
 group by TA.redirect
```

there you go thats the answer. giving back to comunity that i have taken :D

Comment: thank you very much and is it hard to redo it for update ? or that he should add if there are no such records and not create new ones

Comment: i do not understand what do you mean can u write the task out in a fiddle and i will see what i can do it should not be hard to redo it for an update

Comment: OK, I have a table with clients (redirect) and I want to write the answers in columns. They are called zlat1, zlat2 and accrued. Roughly speaking, this is a customer base, but the information is coming all the time and I wanted these values to change. And if there is no client (redirect), then he added them himself (he does not want to do it with pens). The table is called finace_base @Niko Aneli

Comment: ok give me a second

Comment: I can show mine, but it's with an error, I don't know the syntax well

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).